# iphone uitabbar not touchable

Tags: iphone, touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Im having a little problem, cough, a big problem with uitabbar + uitabbarcontroller + interface builder + old ios 4.3 layout.

I cannot select my tabbaritem touching its "bottom" area, like on image bellow. 
(sorry I couldn't post the image itself here)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/547/9fnj.png/

I've already checked whether is something else above it, but there is nothing =(

Could you guys give me a hand?

Thank you!!

**edit 1: think I've got to post the image**
[the problem http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/8529/9fnj.png](http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/8529/9fnj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by myself.

Apparently it was the window frame conflict x interface builder.

Well, the solution was:

```
window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; //in applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

Thank you guys anyway!